# Implementing a tag system for my news system

Tags: php, mysql, tags, full-text-search

I'm trying to build a tag system for my news system. I have finalized a table structure like this:

```
CREATE TABLE article_tags (
id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
tag varchar (255) not null,
primary key (id));


CREATE TABLE article_tags_map (
id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
tag_id int(11) unsigned not null,
article_id int(11) unsigned not null,
primary key (id));
```

Now I'm just wondering if it would make sense to add a full text index to the tag column in article_tags table ?

```
$search = $_POST['search_string'];
$search_result = mysql_query ("SELECT *,  MATCH(tag) AGAINST ($search) AS score 
from article_tags
WHERE MATCH (tag) AGAINST($search) 
order by score desc");
```

Or would I be better off with using LIKE and % wildcard characters ? If I were to use fulltext search, I'm not really sure what threshold should I use for the score ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
SELECT *
from article_tags
WHERE tag like '%$search%'
order by tag desc
```

or

```
 SELECT *
    from article_tags
    WHERE match(tag) against ('%$search%')
    order by tag desc
```

also take a look to this page where they talk about full text searching:  http://devzone.zend.com/26/using-mysql-full-text-searching/

Comment: The column score is not defined

Comment: Thanks. But shouldn't it be ordered by score as opposed to order by tag ?